# Trying to get data from product table when array assigned in order table

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel

I have two table in illustrate below :

Table Product

| id | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sgf500 |
| 2 | sgf700 |
| 3 | sgf800 |

Table Order

| id | Product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1,3 |
| 3 | 2,3 |

How can I get the detail product when I access the data from Order menu in SQL?

I've tried manually this command :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    product
INNER JOIN
    order
WHERE
    order.product_id IN (2,3)
AND 
    orders.id = 3;
```

but I need (2,3) automatically read from order table with refer to product table.

Any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Don't store data as csv - mysql does not have any split string functionality..

Comment: can you suggest me how to separate product_id in order table with correct function?

Comment: Don't do that either have a related  order_detail table which includes the products their prices , quantities etc

Comment: yes, i need to know customer's order what product they buy. so how to relate the order with the product?

Comment: Do a one to many instead.

Comment: This is basic relational database stuff, you should reread your course notes and create the order table containing overarching stuff like customer ,order date etc and an order_detail table containing the order lines linked to order by order id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above, experienced colleagues described the need to revise the data structure and approach to building a database. This obviously needs to be done.

Specifically on the issue, I suggest you look at the option.

```
select o.Id Order_Id,Product_idS,p.Id Product_id,p.Title
from orders o
left join products p
  on instr(concat(',',product_idS,','),concat(',',p.id,','))>0
```

| Order_id | Product_idS | product_id | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | sgf500 |
| 2 | 1,3 | 3 | sgf800 |
| 2 | 1,3 | 1 | sgf500 |
| 3 | 2,3 | 3 | sgf800 |
| 3 | 2,3 | 2 | sgf700 |

When searching Id in Id_list, we frame the value with delimiters to bypass the partial match:

```
instr(',1,12,',',2,')=0 - that is true
instr('1,12','2')=4 - that is error
```

Back to product list

```
select o.Id Order_Id,any_value(Product_idS) Product_idS
    ,group_concat(p.Title order by p.Id) Titles
from orders o
left join products p
  on instr(concat(',',product_idS,','),concat(',',p.id,','))>0
group by o.Id
```

| Order_Id | Product_idS | Titles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | sgf500 |
| 2 | 1,3 | sgf500,sgf800 |
| 3 | 2,3 | sgf700,sgf800 |